# how to use angularjs, prismic.io and browserify together?

Tags: angularjs, browserify

my goal is to use : 
 - Angular 1.3.15 
 - Prismic.io API
 - Browserify

During my tests i can make work : 
* an app with angular and browserify
* an app with angular and prismic.io api

Here's my code when i try to make the three work together.
**app.js**

```
var angular = require('angular');
require('angular-route');
require('angular-prismicio'); 
require('prismic.io');
require('./controllers');

var app = angular.module('monApp', ['ngRoute', 'controllers', 'prismic.io']);

    app.config(['PrismicProvider', function(PrismicProvider) {
        PrismicProvider.setApiEndpoint('myApiUrl');
        PrismicProvider.setAccessToken('');
        PrismicProvider.setClientId('');
        PrismicProvider.setClientSecret('');
        PrismicProvider.setLinkResolver(function(ctx, doc) {
            return '#/document/' + doc.id + '/' + doc.slug + ctx.maybeRefParam;
        });
    }]);
```

I have at the root of my controllers folder :
**index.js**

```
angular.module('controllers', [])
.controller('HomeCtrl', require('./homeCtrl'));
```

and the problem is in the controller:
**HomeCtrl.js**

```
module.exports = function($scope, $location, Prismic){
    var page = "1";
    debugger;
    Prismic.ctx().then(function(ctx){
        ctx.api.form('everything').page(page).ref(ctx.ref).submit(function(err, documents){
            if (err) {
                $location.path('/');
            }
            else {
                $scope.documents = documents;
                ...
            }
        });
    });
};
```

The Prismic object is correctly defined, i can get some of its properties, the problem is on

```
Prismic.ctx()
```

in the debugger it gives me this error :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Api' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you get an answer to this question? You will need the prismic.io javascript included in your html. I installed it using bower:

```
<script src="bower_components/prismic.io/dist/prismic.io.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks, the example i give use your solution, and sadly i didn't have an answer. The problem comes with the integration between browserify and prismic.io.js. I give up for the moment.